# UWP: How to catch the click of a listview part from another listview in the viewmodel instead of code-behind?

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

I have this listview:

```
<Page
    x:Class="DataBase.ControlsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding CustomersViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView Name="HeaderList" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="Bisque">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ListView Name="SubItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Project}" ItemClick="SubItemClick">
                        <x:String>SubItem 1</x:String>
                        <x:String>SubItem 2</x:String>
                        <x:String>SubItem 3</x:String>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
        <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
        <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

All I want is to catch the click of a subItem(**ItemClick="SubItemClick">**) in my CustomersViewModel. Is that possible? I know for the sub-items list items, the data is a Project which is just a data model, it does not contain any click handler. But, how can I catch the click in the view model and not in the code-behind?

Also I'm uploading a picture to visualise what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Justin XL said, the answer I was looking for is this: 
`ItemClick="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=HeaderList}"`

Comment: Hi, can you explain  where you made that change?  Cause, I can not find ElementName of Parent ListView from Child ListView ..Please share if you have come across a solution for this problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is a `ClickCommand` in your viewmodel. But since the `ListView` control doesn't expose a `ItemClickCommand`, one common way is to use a *behavior* to establish the connection between your `ClickCommand` and the `ItemClick` event.

This particular behavior you are looking for is called `InvokeCommandAction`, which can be found in this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/).

Basically the end result would look something like this -

```
<ListView Name="HeaderList" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=HeaderList}">
            <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: What I am saying is that I need the "ClickCommand" to exist in CustomersViewModel and for the second ListView, the ItemSource is bound to a Project not to a CustomersViewModel. So I need somehow to send the click event back to CustomersViewModel.

Comment: @mbob how about using MvvmLightas messenger pattern to share the clicked item across? Are your two view models bound to different pages?

Comment: Customers is a property of CustomersViewModel which is bound to the main listview (Item 1, Item 2, etc). Every Customer will contain a list of Projects which will be the ItemSource for the second list(SubItem 1, Subitem 2, etc).  So "Project" is not a viewmodel anymore, it is only a data model.

Comment: OK, so you just need an `ElementName` binding to map to your `CustomersViewModel`'s command. Something like this: `ItemClick="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=HeaderList}"`.

Comment: Also, another approach is to use `ListView`'s group header feature to display a grouped list rather than having nested `ListView`s.

Comment: this worked for me: ItemClick="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=HeaderList}"

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

Comment: Hello @JustinXL, I have the same problem setup however using ElementName, my nested list view does not find the parentListview. How can I ensure that nested listview always finds container listview's name as elementName?